# Android Nougat 7.1.1 broadcastReceiver does not work anymore

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, wifi

Using Nougat 7.1.1 on my Nexus 5X

Having updated the newest gradle today, the broadcastReceiver suddently does not work anymore. Before that it worked nicely - no issues. But suddenly no longer!! This is very bad!

What is going on ??? What do I need to do in order to get it work again ??

My gradle-compiles look as follows:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```

Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score -1):

I finally found a solution: If I factory-reset my Nexus 5X and re-install Android Nougat 7.1.1, then my code works again ! No idea what corrupted the mobile install in the meantime ???